# What format is required to import a date into google spreadsheet

Tags: forms, google-sheets

With the help of "stackoverflow" and it's users I'm using an app to import data into a Google spreadsheet. The problem is I have a date question on the form, and can not manage to import it. If I change the format (in the forms) to text, the data imports as it has been sent from the app, but when I change it back to date, nothing.

I've believe I've tried all the usual date formats (dd/mm/yyyy, mm/dd/yyyy, yyyy/mm/dd, yyyy/dd/mm) as well as yy for the above and also numerical.

I know that the Google form shows the date in the users format and that is not a problem. It shows up correctly in the spreadsheet in my local format (dd/mm/yyyy).

Does anyone know what format the form uses to send the data to the spreadsheet, or anyway to find out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after using wikipedia, and trying every different format it works by using the format yyyy-mm-dd