# Format to enter a Date in Google Forms

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a drop-down list of dates I want users of a form to select from. I have tried mm/dd//yy, mm/dd/yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy/mm/dd and MMM-DD-YYY, but the data that ends up in the Sheet is always 12/31/1969 (25568.6666666667 if I change the display format). What format can I use to get a date successfully imported?

The answer in this thread didn't work for me: [What format is required to import a date into google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036913/what-format-is-required-to-import-a-date-into-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: Is this a Google Form?  Is it an HTML form?  How is the data being written to the sheet?

Comment: It's a Google Form. I have a script that populates the spreadsheet. If I use a "Date" field in the form, it imports correctly. However I want the user to pick from a preselected set of dates, so I can't use the Date data type.

Comment: Actually, most of these formats seem to work. I had some naming errors for the columns of my spreadsheet so the data was not being written correctly

Comment: So, you found the problem?

Comment: Yes, thanks for checking

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The format mm/dd/yyyy works; I had a problem in the naming of the columns of the spreadsheet which was the source of the problem.